# Limits without L'Hopital: $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ and then $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ and then use it to
>   find $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}$

I am using the trig rule $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

I am getting stuck on the negative one and trying to get rid of it.

Comment: whoever -1 my post if so rude

Comment: You mean you want to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {sin(x)}{x}$ ?

Comment: Threr is no such thing like 'rule $\sin(x)/0=1$'. You can't divide by 0. Do you mean rule $\lim_{x\to 0}sin(x)/x = 1$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$

$=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}$

$=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos x}$

$=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\cos x}$

$=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\cdot \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1}{1+\cos x}$

$=\left(\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2\cdot \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1}{1+\cos x}$

$=1\cdot \frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{x^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x^2}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Since $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,+\infty)$, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos{x}}}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\quad{k=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}\\\text{because x>0   },1-\cos x=2\sin^2 (\frac x2)>0\to \space k>0 \\k^2=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}.\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}\\k^2=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}.\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos x}}{x}\\k^2=
\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{{1-\cos x}}{x^2}
\\k^2=
\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{{1-\cos x}}{x^2}.\frac{{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x}\\k^2=\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{{\sin^2x}}{x^2}.\frac{1}{1+\cos x}=1.\frac 12\\\to k=\pm \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \to \text{ we know k>0 } \to k=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}}$$